# Failure 7547 Target row updated by multiple source rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm getting this error message when I run my query in Teradata SQL Server "Failure 7547 Target row updated by multiple source rows."

I know that I have to delete the duplicate rows but I don't know how to do it.

```
MERGE INTO  ${DTTK_COMMON_default_database}.LA1DB51CTERELCTE AS TGT 
USING (SELECT SWTBAJAF
,NUMCLIENTE
,CSI
,CTR_NUMCSIR
,CTE_NUMREL
,CTR_TIPOREL
,CTR_NUMNOM
,CTR_TIPPAR
,CTR_PORCENT
,CTR_PUESTO
,CTE_FEALTA_2K
,CTE_FEMODI_2K
,FECINF
FROM ${DTTK_COMMON_default_database}.LA1DB51CTERELCTE_STG)
AS SRC
ON
TGT.NUMCLIENTE = SRC.NUMCLIENTE AND
TGT.CSI = SRC.CSI AND  
TGT.CTR_NUMCSIR = SRC.CTR_NUMCSIR AND 
TGT.CTE_NUMREL = SRC.CTE_NUMREL AND 
TGT.CTR_TIPOREL = SRC.CTR_TIPOREL 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET
  SWTBAJAF = SRC.SWTBAJAF
 ,CTR_NUMNOM   = SRC.CTR_NUMNOM
 ,CTR_TIPPAR   = SRC.CTR_TIPPAR
 ,CTR_PORCENT  = SRC.CTR_PORCENT
 ,CTR_PUESTO   = SRC.CTR_PUESTO
 ,CTE_FEALTA_2K = SRC.CTE_FEALTA_2K
 ,CTE_FEMODI_2K = SRC.CTE_FEMODI_2K
         ,FECINF     = SRC.FECINF
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
(SWTBAJAF
,NUMCLIENTE
,CSI
,CTR_NUMCSIR
,CTE_NUMREL
,CTR_TIPOREL
,CTR_NUMNOM
,CTR_TIPPAR
,CTR_PORCENT
,CTR_PUESTO
,CTE_FEALTA_2K
,CTE_FEMODI_2K
,FECINF)
VALUES
(SRC.SWTBAJAF
,SRC.NUMCLIENTE
,SRC.CSI
,SRC.CTR_NUMCSIR
,SRC.CTE_NUMREL
,SRC.CTR_TIPOREL
,SRC.CTR_NUMNOM
,SRC.CTR_TIPPAR
,SRC.CTR_PORCENT
,SRC.CTR_PUESTO
,SRC.CTE_FEALTA_2K
,SRC.CTE_FEMODI_2K
,SRC.FECINF);
```

As a result I need to delete the duplicate rows from my table.

Comment: This says the combination of ON columns (NUMCLIENTE, CSI, CTR_NUMCSIR, CTE_NUMREL, CTR_TIPOREL) is not unique in the source LA1DB51CTERELCTE_STG table. If the source rows are 100% identical, it could be as simple as adding DISTINCT to the source query. Otherwise you have to come up with a rule to determine which one you want to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got multiple rows for the same key you should find out what causes the problem and how to fix it.

For duplicate rows a simple SELECT DISTINCT would be sufficient.

If only the key is duplicate, you could do an aggregation (max/sum/avg), but in most cases you have to determine which rows is the *most current*, e.g.

```
USING (SELECT SWTBAJAF
,NUMCLIENTE
,CSI
,CTR_NUMCSIR
,CTE_NUMREL
,CTR_TIPOREL
,CTR_NUMNOM
,CTR_TIPPAR
,CTR_PORCENT
,CTR_PUESTO
,CTE_FEALTA_2K
,CTE_FEMODI_2K
,FECINF
FROM ${DTTK_COMMON_default_database}.LA1DB51CTERELCTE_STG
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER(PARTITION BY NUMCLIENTE, CSI, CTR_NUMCSIR, CTE_NUMREL, CTR_TIPOREL
        ORDER BY ??? DESC) = 1 -- any timestamp/sequence to find the best match?
) AS SRC
```